# iptables - Clear all PREROUTING rules with a specific destination address

Tags: iptables, bash, grep

I have a script that adds iptable PREROUTING rules.  They all have the same to address.
When I run this:

```
 iptables --list PREROUTING -t nat
```

I see output like this:

```
 DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             165.193.122.18      tcp dpt:https to:192.168.2.1:443
 DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             63.135.91.11        tcp dpt:https to:192.168.2.1:443
 DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             63.135.90.224       tcp dpt:https to:192.168.2.1:443
```

It seems like I should be able to drop all these rules by writing a command like this...

```
"drop all PREROUTING rules that go to 192.168.2.1:443"
```

So, in looking at the options for itables it looks like I need to use the -D option.  But I don't know the rulenum to give it. :-(

So, I probably need to query for existing rules, grep to limit it to destination 192.168.2.1:443, and run -D passing the rulenum for each one.  I have no idea how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line_num in $(sudo iptables --line-numbers --list PREROUTING -t nat | awk '$7=="to:192.168.2.1:443" {print $1}')
do
  # You can't just delete lines here because the line numbers get reordered
  # after deletion, which would mean after the first one you're deleting the
  # wrong line. Instead put them in a reverse ordered list.
  LINES="$line_num $LINES"
done

# Delete the lines, last to first.
for line in $LINES
do
  sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING $line
done

unset LINES
```

You may need to adjust the field number in awk if it's not matching.

Comment: This worked great.  I had to change the field to $9.  After that it worked exactly as I hoped.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to simplify the line reversal with tac:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(sudo iptables --line-numbers --list PREROUTING -t nat | awk '$7=="to:192.168.2.1:443" {print $1}' | tac)
do
  # You can't just delete lines here because the line numbers get reordered
  # after deletion, which would mean after the first one you're deleting the
  # wrong line. Instead put them in a reverse ordered list.
  sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING $line
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following one-liner:

```
sudo iptables -S | grep $pattern | cut -d " " -f 2- | xargs -L1 sudo iptables -D
```

Where $pattern is your desired pattern.

I recommend you first echo the results of this command though, to avoid drama

Comment: In case it helps somebody, my Ubuntu 16.04 didn't have the `-S` option in `iptables`, and had a slightly different output, so I ended up with this: `iptables -L -vt nat --line-number | grep $pattern | cut -d " " -f 0-3 | xargs -L1 iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING
`

Answer (score 0):

Use `--line-numbers` to display the rule number, grep and awk it and you have it.

```
# iptables -vnL -t nat --line-numbers |grep 10.1.1.0|awk '{print $1}' 
1
```

You can then use `for` to clear all the rules matching one specific IP.

```
# for rule in $(iptables -vnL -t nat --line-numbers |grep 10.1.1.0|awk '{print $1}'); do iptables -D INPUT $rule; done
```

Remember those numbers are shown per table, so you may need to limit the list command by table and clear one by one.

Comment: This won't work because the rules are listed in ascending order. Once you delete the first one all the other rules will re-order and have a different number. Once you get to the second rule that you want to delete you're now deleting the wrong line. You'd have to regenerate the list after *each and every* deletion.

Comment: Not a real motive to -1 right?